# Qt and OpenGL: How do we use glu* functions when using QOpenGLFunctions?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to get my feet wet with both OpenGL and Qt (5.6) simultaneously and ran into this problem. I code in C++ on Windows if that matters.

How do we use glu* functions (say `gluCylinder`) when using `QOpenGLWidget` with `QOpenGLFunctions`? I can get my program to compile if I include `<GL/GLU.h>`, but this will invoke the global gl* opengl functions (from `GL/GL.h`) and not those of `QOpenGLFunctions`.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? Or just don't like GLU using GL functions directly and not via Qt proxies (which can be problemmatic since it implements GL ES 2.0, while GLU built on top of old GL 1)? If you're on compatibility profile it should be ok.

Comment: @keltar TBH, I am still in learning mode and trying to find my way about doing things properly in OpenGL via Qt, hence this was for the purposes of tutorials that used glu* functions. The QOpenGLFunctions family of classes just struck me as a nice way to program against a guaranteed OpenGL API. I was just wondering if I there is a way to use GLU functions with it, that's all.

Comment: You can't (since GLU have no API to pass function pointers), but in most cases it doesn't matter. These functions are the same, GL calls use 'current context'. If your context is GL1.1-capable (i.e. not GL ES and not core profile) - there is no problem, but GLU have no ideas about newer functionality that can change GL behavior, so you still can break things with e.g. active shader program. With that in mind, - you can use GLU, but it is possible it will add more problems if you use newer GL functionality (then again, said tutorials that use GLU probably don't do that).

Comment: @keltar Thanks! That clarifies things quite a bit.